# Jquery href click - how can I fire up an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this anchor and on click I would like to popup something.
This href is within a page that has other hrefs.

```
<a class="sign_new" href="#sign_up">Sign up</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href = "sign_up"]').click(function(){
      alert('Sign new href executed.'); 
   }); 
});
```

The above code does not fire up.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It doesn't because the href value is not `sign_up`.It is `#sign_up`. Try like below,
You need to add "#" to indicate the id of the href value.

```
$('a[href="#sign_up"]').click(function(){
  alert('Sign new href executed.'); 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pnGbP/

Answer (score 9):

If you own the HTML code then it might be wise to assign an id to this href. Then your code would look like this:

```
<a id="sign_up" class="sign_new">Sign up</a>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sign_up').click(function(){
        alert('Sign new href executed.');
    });
});
```

If you do not own the HTML then you'd need to change $('#sign_up') to $('a.sign_new'). You might also fire event.stopPropagation() if you have a href in anchor and do not want it handled (AFAIR return false might work as well).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sign_up').click(function(event){
        alert('Sign new href executed.');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a .sign_new').click(function(){
      alert('Sign new href executed.'); 
   }); 
});
```

You've mixed up the `class` and `href` names / selector type.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `click` event to anchors with an *href* attribute with value `sign_new`.

Either bind anchors with class `sign_new` or bind anchors with href value `#sign_up`. I would prefer the former.